# Hibernate/JPA: em.merge( new MyEntity(id) ) returns proxy without collections

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge

Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0 or 3.6.10

```
MyEntity {
    @Id   // NOT @GeneratedValue
    long cislo;

    @OneToMany( ... )
    List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList();


    public MyEntity( long cislo ) { this.cislo = cislo; }
    ...
}
```

And then, in a DAO:

```
MyEntity ent = new MyEntity( id );
ent.addItem( new Item( ... ) );
ent.addItem( new Item( ... ) );
ent = em.merge( ent );
```

1) Why do I need to use `merge()`, not `persist()` which would complain that the entity is detached? Is it due to manually set ID?

2) Why does this merge return a proxy without the collections set?

3) *Most important:* How can I get fully initialized entity from `merge()`?
    Other than setting `EAGER` on the member colections.
    I could use the original object, but I'm curious whether it's possible.
    I could query for the entity as well but that seems like wasting of resources.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Why are you using "Session.merge()" here? Merge is normally used for re-attaching a detached entity instance to a Hibernate/JPA session - this normally happens when you reuse entity instances outside a session (for example, in the view layer) and you want to propagate any changes to these instances to the database using the Session.

2.) The Hibernate documentation says that "If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of it and return it as a newly persistent instance."
    In your case, since you're trying to "merge" a brand new instance, Hibernate will first save it to the database, then re-fetch it as a new entity instance. The reason why a proxy is returned is because Hibernate lazy-loads any Collection by default. In order to ensure that a getter method for the collection returns the actual collection. Hibernate creates a proxy.

3.) I'm curious on why aren't you using Session.save() here.

Comment: Maybe you missed that it's JPA with Hibernate as underlying impl, not pure Hibernate.

Comment: @OndraŽižka - My comment still holds good. The `merge()` method, whether used from JPA's `EntityManager` or Hibernate's `Session` works in the same manner.

Comment: No offense, but it renders 1) invalid since there's nothing else to use, and 3) since there's no save(). Thanks for answering 2). Regarding 3), seems like I simply have to get used to this behavior of merge()...